# Use Ogury react native

Tags: react-native, interstitial

Using documentation:

For implementation:
Android: https://ogury-ltd.gitbook.io/android/
iOS: https://ogury-ltd.gitbook.io/ios/

For interstitial:
Android: https://ogury-ltd.gitbook.io/android/ad-formats/interstitial-ad
iOS: https://ogury-ltd.gitbook.io/ios/ad-formats/interstitial-ad

I don't understand how to use Ogury with React Native.

Is it possible ?

I tried to implement it natively and I searched on google but couldn't find an answer.